# Jquery slider for mobile web sites

Tags: jquery, mobile, slider

I'm looking for a slider that can autoscale the images, to a specific screen size. The rest of the mobile website I'm working on is made with procentage but it's really hard for me to find a image slider that can work with 100% in both height and width.

The problem is that theres a milion screensizes when we talk phones, so it's not a good idea to have a slider that can auto scale to fit a specific screen size, and of course fit the screen againg if the user tilt their phone.

Comment: Looking for something like a NivoSlider. The with and height has to be done in procentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You might want to give something like this a shot.](http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/touchslider/) It's a tutorial by Zack Grossbart on developing just what you're looking for. Between [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/), you should be able to quickly develop what you need.

Comment: Great article, but I'm looking for something similar to the NivoSlider, to implement on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Go for [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/), easy to use and configure. Have implemented it on quite a few projects and works well on almost all browsers. If you're comfortable with Nivo slider, you can go ahead with that as well, might need to make a few tweaks in the css that comes along with the plugin.

You would need to fix the width of the image to 100%. Might wanna try CSS inheritance or use !important.